# WPFの描画更新方法が知りたい

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

[image: WPFアプリの部品の配置]

図のような、ActiveXを用いたWPFアプリを作成しています。
WPFアプリに張り付けたPopup部品とActiveX部品のデータバインドしたVisibilityに対して、表示/非表示を連続で繰り返すと、
あるタイミングでActiveX部品の描画更新がされないことがあります。
Popup部品の描画更新のみ行われて、背面にあるActiveX部品の描画更新が行われなかったのだと推測しています。
ActiveX部品の描画更新をするため、WPFの全画面描画更新をしてあげる必要があると考えているのですが、その手段が分かりません。
ご教授いただきたいです。

開発環境
VisualStudio2017, C#, .netframework4.6.1

Comment: この記事が参考になるかも。[Handling a bubbling event raised from a modal dialog in main window](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7825379/9014308)

Comment: ありがとうございます。参考記事は、別ウインドウからの親ウインドウへの通知方法が記載されていました。
私の図の書き方が悪かったのですが、図のPopup部品はWPF標準のPopup部品になります。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

本質的な解決ではありませんが、描画更新できしました。

- Windowの背景色とサイズが同じBitmapを用意し、ActiveX部品と同時に表示、非表示する。

見た目上、ActiveX部品の描画更新できていなかった残像部分だけが描画更新されます。
ActiveX部品の背面にある部品を描画すればなんでもいいです。